# Django:csrf token

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

When ever I am submitting the form i am getting `csrfmiddlewaretoken=Mlhg830h3mLCuVD0sl1MTXUnSxFHMib6ZYtXmfZ8k1jZL1DA2IrNwzGVp2PymTCN&choice=1`
in my url, even after including the `csrf` token also

```
{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}
<form>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
        <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ froloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}">
        <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" >{{ choice.choice_text }}</label><br/>
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" value="Vote" />
</form>
```

I have `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware` in my middleware settings.

How to resolve this issue

Comment: Resolve what? You haven't actually described a problem here, only stated that Django is doing what it's supposed to be doing (what I do see, though, is that you are making your form send a GET request, even though it's clearly meant to modify data on your server: that should be using POST, with the associated csrf decorator on the post handling def, instead)

Comment: Thank you Mike, my problem got resolved.'

Comment: Stackoverflow is about helping people solve their problems, so if you solved your problem, please either write an answer that explains how you solved it, or: if it was "something silly", please delete your question.